Python. How to use requests in Firefox
I want to get data from a website, but I need to open the link specifically in Firefox without opening the browser itself. how do I do that?
I'm trying to use a webbrowser, but it opens the browser. I'm trying to use requests, but I don't know how to specify Firefox.

Please clarify what you are trying to ask. To me it sounds like: "I want Firefox but not a web browser.".

I think instead of requests you need Selenium or Playwright
In both selenium and Playwright you can specify which browser you would like to open. There is also a headless mode which will open the browser in the background.
